# Who will handle 'virtualenv' OR 'virtualenvwrapper'?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

Okay so I have installed virtualenv and with tha I have got my pip installed.
Then, I have installed virtualenvwrapper using `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`, and also have set up my *$WORKON_HOME* variable and settings.

Now I have a doubt, if I switch to some random directory say `cd ~/Code/Django/`
and create an env there using `virtualenv env1`
who will handle it, I mean, can I use virtualenvwrapper with it and why does it not show up when I do `workon`, only the environments in the `~/.virtualenvs/` show up.!

And would this new environment be as secure as the one created by the virtualenvwrapper???

Please tell me if I am wrong somewhere!!

Answer (score 0):

`workon` gets list of virtual environments from `WORKON_HOME` environment variable, that points to `~/.virtualenvs` in your case (default).

Quote from [docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#location-of-environments):

> The variable WORKON_HOME tells virtualenvwrapper where to place your
>   virtual environments. The default is $HOME/.virtualenvs. If the
>   directory does not exist when virtualenvwrapper is loaded, it will be
>   created automatically.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But what if I create another project with the help of `virtualenv` and not `virtualenvwrapper` ???
I meant can I also make a soft link to that in the WORKON_HOME directory to work.??

Comment: Yes, if you create virtual environment via `virtualenv` you can make a link to it via `ln -s` from `WORKON_HOME` directory and it will work.